# ERROR: composer is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, vagrant-provision

Hi I've been trying to make ansible run composer install to install all the content in my composer.json inside my laravel file. But I'm getting this error **ERROR: composer is not a legal parameter in an Ansible task or handler** I'm not sure what's causing this. Below are the content of my playbook.

```
---
- name: Install PHP5+
  apt: name={{ item }} update_cache=yes state=latest
  with_items:
    - git
    - mcrypt
    - php5-cli
    - php5-curl
    - php5-fpm
    - php5-intl
    - php5-json
    - php5-mcrypt
    - php5-sqlite
    - sqlite3
  notify:
    - Reload Nginx
- name: install composer
  shell: curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=/usr/local/bin --filename=composer
  args:
    creates: /usr/local/bin/composer
- composer:
    command: install
    working_dir: /path/to/project
```

Now if I do vagrant provision I'm getting the Composer is not a legal parameter. Basically I just wanted to run composer and tell composer to install all dependency inside my composer json

http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/composer_module.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will usually just use a role from Ansible Galaxy, such as [geerlingguy.composer](https://galaxy.ansible.com/geerlingguy/composer/) for such requirements.

According to the [Ansible Docs](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/composer_module.html), the `composer` module is available from Ansible 1.6, but requires composer to be pre-installed on the executable path.

Installing Composer is usually going to be a multi-step process, if you use the installer (from the geerlingguy.composer tasks/main.yml).

- Check if Composer is installed.
- Download Composer installer (with Ansible `get_url`).
- Run Composer installer (via PHP executable).
- Move Composer into globally-accessible location.
- Update Composer to latest version (if configured).
- Ensure composer directory exists.
- Add GitHub OAuth token for Composer (if configured).

Or, you can download the latest version, https://getcomposer.org/composer.phar or a tagged version make it executable and move it into an appropriate directory.

Comment: It seems that my Ansible version is indeed a lower version. I have 1.5 ansible. I did a pre-installation of my ansible in a .sh file and run it when vagrant boots up

Comment: I fix the issue and did an apt-get update first before installing ansible to make sure ansible is in its latest version and now I was able to run composer install. Thanks for pointing out the version that composer is avaialble

Comment: @MadzmarUllang If you were using Ansible 1.5, why did you tag the question with [tag:ansible-2.x]?

Comment: @Alister because at first I didn't know that the version was the problem and I thought that I have installed the latest ansible which is 2.0